# Could anyone vouch for these Taiwanese wire connectors?

Tags: safety, connectors

I'm looking for an alternative to WAGO wire connectors and stumbled upon this one (https://www.heavypower.com.tw/english/product/102). Does it look legit specifically its UL certification?

Comment: See [here](https://iaeimagazine.org/2004/march2004/how-can-we-tell-if-a-ul-listing-mark-is-counterfeit/) for a contact name and email to query about possible counterfeit use of UL marks.    If nobody is importing or selling it in the USA I don't know if it would count as counterfeit but you could pursue that question with the same person.   Who knows, maybe the Taiwanese maker obtained proper UL certification in hope of finding a US distributor but they have not yet been successful.  So, maybe it's fake or maybe it's a business opportunity.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the exemplar items are UL listed.  However, you will be sent substitutes which are not.

### Buy things at bricks-and-mortar retail in your country

The way we keep unsafe crud out of the USA (and Canada and Europe do the same) is by having consumer protection agencies inflict serious consequences on *bricks-and-mortar* establishments in the country - specifically, their assets in country, such as stores, inventory, bank accounts and the like.

So if you're a maker of unsafe crud trying to circumvent those laws, the standard ploy is **to have no assets in-country** - and sit "safely" in a foreign land beyond the reach of your country's enforcement.  And deliver products thusly:

- Direct mail from the "safe" country (hoping Customs will be too busy with drugs and weapons to intercept some non-listed connectors)
- Ship from a "drop ship" warehouse in your country that is a "free trade zone" meaning it's not technically imported until it ships from that warehouse.  *Amazon Fulfillment* is the #1 drop-ship warehouse in the West. Things sold off eBay, DealExtreme, Wish *and of course Amazon* ship via this. If ordered on Amazon, "Prime" shipping applies.
- Use a patsy, a local person to "take the fall" (have their assets seized; it helps if they have no assets to seize).

However with bricks-and-mortar sales, there is most likely to be a competent "chain of custody" - meaning it went from the factory to the manufacturer's *own* in-country warehouses, where samples were inspected, and then on to the retailer and to you.  All of whom "have collateral" in the Tuco sense of the word - have assets to seize. They would suffer gravely for selling dangerous stuff.

Does your country forbid wire nuts? They are safe as houses if one takes the time to self-examine ones work and learn to do them *properly*.